# Union or merge tables to accommodate for specific needs in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 temporary tables that create two columns for mobile numbers;
mobile 1 has all national and international numbers, and mobile two has a handful of numbers that needed to be converted from `++41` to `0041` for example.

How can I merge these numbers into one column, whereby I keep everything from mobile1 except for the handful of changed ++ numbers

It looks like:

```
mobile 1         cust      mobile 2
-------------------------------------------
078998899       98743872
079445544       12342343   
+637976945247   41768999    00637976945247
+41405355893    98767856    0041405355893
+41412387946    43789347    0041412387946
+4113120464     85903479    000413120464
```

And it should be :

```
mobile final       cust    
----------------------------------
078998899          98743872
079445544          12342343   
00637976945247     41768999 
0041405355893      98767856 
0041412387946      43789347 
000413120464       85903479
```

I tried this here, but it is not happy about the brackets, and I would be happy for some help here. This is for SQL Server

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp_UNION 
FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM [#national_numbers] 
     UNION
     SELECT *
     FROM [#international_numbers] 
     UNION
     SELECT * 
     FROM [#plusplus_numbers]
     UNION) v
```

Comment: Remove the last `union` you only use `union` between queries, not before or after.

Comment: I assume you can already replace "+" with "00"

Answer (score 0):

You can set two column data into one column based on condition with help of CASE WHEN and LEFT,CHARINDEX,SUBSTRING and Like.

I stronly recommanded to use  CHARINDEX for better performance, [Here are the results, in milli-seconds, in our LIKE vs SUBSTRING vs LEFT/RIGHT vs CHARINDEX speed tests.](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/like-vs-substring-vs-leftright-vs-charindex)

```
create table #Test (mobile1 varchar(100),cust varchar(100),mobile2 varchar(100))

insert into #Test values('078998899','98743872',null)
insert into #Test values('079445544','12342343',null)
insert into #Test values('+637976945247','41768999','00637976945247')
insert into #Test values('+41405355893','98767856','0041405355893')
insert into #Test values('+41412387946','43789347','0041412387946')
insert into #Test values('+4113120464','85903479','000413120464')
```

Using CharIndex:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX ('+',mobile1)=1 THEN mobile2 ELSE mobile1 END As MobileNo, cust from #Test
```